# Django settings.py variables in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

I'm encountering a very strange error. I have an app ID defined in my `settings.py` file like so:

```
CARDSPRING_APP_ID = '################'
```

This works on nearly every page in my site, except for one. Strangely enough, other variables work. In a script section on the page, I have the following:

```
alert("cs appid=" + {{ CARDSPRING_APP_ID }} + 
" sectoken=" + {{ securityToken }} + 
" timestamp= " +{{ timestamp }} + 
" hash = " + {{ digestedHash }} + 
" ccnum " + $('.card-number').val() + 
" exp" + $('.expiration-month').val() + $('.expiration-year').val() + 
" user = " + {{ csid }});
```

When the page is rendered, it evaluates to this

```
alert("cs appid=" +  + 
" sectoken=" + DDFJRMZXD12WVWHFFC###### + 
" timestamp= " +1346183125 + 
" hash = " + a929b3aec9179c700c09d###### + 
" ccnum " + $('.card-number').val() + 
" exp" + $('.expiration-month').val() + $('.expiration-year').val() + 
" user = " + SG1###);
```

Importantly, `{{ CARDSPRING_APP_ID }}` has evaluated to nothing. Does anyone know why this might be the case? Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I tried creating a `context_processors.py` file as described in the answer below, and made sure to add it to the appropriate spot in `settings.py` . I still don't have any luck -- it evaluates on one page, but not on the other

**UPDATE 2**

The template is called with this command:

```
return render_to_response('howto'+str(number)+'.html',locals(),context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

**UPDATE 3**
Got it to work -- needed to add this to my settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    "myapp.context_processors.cardspring",
)
```

Comment: Do you have a context processor that gives `CARDSPRING_APP_ID` its value in templates?

Comment: I'm not sure -- how would I check? I know that `CARDSPRING_APP_ID` evaluates appropriately on other pages in the site, just not on this one

Comment: How do you pass `CARDSPRING_APP_ID` to those pages then? It may be better to add it as a context processor anyway as that adds it automatically to all pages.

Comment: @Simeon Visser That's what I'm not sure of -- in the past, all I had to do was define it in settings.py and it'd automatically be accessible in my templates. Is there anything I need to add to the html itself to make sure it looks in settings.py (or in the context processsors, for that matter)?

Comment: Variables from `settings.py` aren't added automaticly to templates context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a file called `context_processors.py` and write the following context processor:

```
from django.conf import settings

def cardspring(request):
    return { 'CARDSPRING_APP_ID': settings.CARDSPRING_APP_ID }
```

Then add `your.location.context_processors.cardspring` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your Django settings file, where `your.location` is the location of your `context_processors.py` file.

Comment: I'm looking in `settings.py` now, but don't see `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'. Should I add this?

Comment: @mythander889: Yes, in case it is not there then you should add it. Make sure you also add the default values (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#template-context-processors ) and then add your own context processor.

Comment: I have added it as you described with a little help from [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/), but still haven't had any luck. Is there something I have to include in the html file itself? That's the only thing I can think of that could be different

Comment: Nothing needs to be added to the HTML file but it could be that your view is not using the context processors. Are you using `render_to_response` to create the response in your view?

Comment: Yes -- I call it with this:

return render_to_response('howto'+str(number)+'.html',locals(),context_instance= RequestContext(request))

Comment: @mythander889: That's good because `RequestContext` calls the context processors. Then I'm not sure why the template variable has no value. Is there anything that you may have configured that causes your Django project to behave differently?

Comment: I got it to work -- the template context processors weren't loading correctly. Thank you!